# Find specific directory and have it as working directory

Tags: bash, find

I have no problem to find the subdirectory I want with:

```
find /media/USBdrive/ -type d -mtime 1
```

From there I need to get this subdirectory (of snapshots) as working directory from where I will run the command `mencodex...` to create my video.

I tried `-exec cd {} /;....` and a lot of other things but no avail
I am lost here

thank you for your help

My purpose further is to create a script but first I need to check the command

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd $(find /media/USBdrive/ -type d -mtime 1)
```

Or, more properly, as Glenn suggests with double quotes to handle spaces in your target directory name.

By the way... when you run "find ... -exec xyz", it creates a subshell and runs your command (i.e. xyz) in that subshell till it exits and then it runs another subshell for the next file it finds that matches your search. So when you run "find ... -exec cd somewhere". it does actually cd to that directory, but it then exits. If you really wanted to, you could put all the commands you want in a new script, called say "DoEverything" and run like this:

```
find ... -exec DoEverything {} \;
```

but that would involve another script, and the way Glenn and I suggested is cleaner.

Comment: I would urge you to do error-checking to be sure you landed exactly where you expected. One day the "find" might return nothing and you will end up executing "cd" and landing in your login directory for example...

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the cd command in your *current* shell: changing directories in a subshell or a script will not affect your current shell:

```
cd "$(find /media/USBdrive/ -type d -mtime 1)"
```